# Get total hours in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, sum, blazor

I have a foreach loop that shows each employee's clock in and clock out on a work order.  I've been able to calculate and show those time as a total of hours/minutes/seconds.  I used the following code.

```
@if(employeehour.ClockOut != null)
{                               
    TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(employeehour.ClockOut.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(employeehour.ClockIn.ToString()));

    double totalHours = duration.TotalHours;
    calculateHours.Add(totalHours);
    string formatted = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                           duration.Duration().Days > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} day{1} ", duration.Days, duration.Days == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
                           duration.Duration().Hours > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} hour{1} ", duration.Hours, duration.Hours == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
                           duration.Duration().Minutes > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} minute{1} ", duration.Minutes, duration.Minutes == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
                           duration.Duration().Seconds > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} second{1} ", duration.Seconds, duration.Seconds == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty);
    <p>@formatted</p>
}
```

@formatted gives the result as shown in the following image.

[image]

I want to total the formatted hours of each row in my foreach, ultimately to get the 'Total Man Hours' worked on a project.

I need a total of all hours in the Hours column.  Any thought on this?  I need this outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: theres no loop there

Comment: You already have a `List<double>` called `calculateHours`. What does this do, and why doesn't it give you what you want?  A better way would probably be to use Linq's  `Sum` method, but unfortunately my arm is broken right now and it's hard for me to type out sample code for you.

Comment: Don't edit your question to add your solution. Instead, post it as an answer. You can then accept it after the appropriate delay

Answer (score 1):

In your code the calculateHours would just get the hours. I am assuming if 2 people worked 2.5 hours you would want your total hours to be 5 total man hours not 4.

Initialize a TimeSpan outside of your for loop

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();
```

and then add your duration in each iteration

```
totalTime = totalTime.Add(duration);
```

then use your format the same way after the loop

Comment: I get where this is going and why, however, the 'duration' errors outside of the foreach loop.  I need to show this elsewhere on the page for the total hours.


Error (active) CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Comment: You should read this answer more carefully. Total time needs to be defined outside the `foreach` loop as a `TimeSpan`, but duration is added to the total time inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, the foreach loop was mentioned in your post but not visible in the code so I just stated to put it outside. I am not sure what would cause that error, It should have only used timespans. One timespan set before your foreach loop to hold the cumulative total and another one which is set for each iteration which gets added to the total timespan. I am not sure why it gets converted to a double though, keeping it as timespans rather than converting to double will give you better precision (depending how many employees it may be negligible).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the logic from the foreach loop and moved it to it's own function.

```
private List<double> calculateHours = new List<double>();
private double calculatedHours;
private string formattedTotalHours;
private string formattedTotalMinutes;

private void calculateTotalHours()
{
    calculateHours.Clear();

    foreach(var e in employeehours){

        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(e.ClockOut.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(e.ClockIn.ToString()));

        double totalHours = duration.TotalHours;
        calculateHours.Add(totalHours);
    }

    calculatedHours = calculateHours.Sum();
    formattedTotalHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(calculatedHours).ToString(@"hh");
    formattedTotalMinutes = TimeSpan.FromHours(calculatedHours).ToString(@"mm");
}
```

and in my Razor code:

```
<p><b>Total Man Hours:</b> @formattedTotalHours hours @formattedTotalMinutes minutes</p>
```

[image]